# Validating DITA in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, validation, dita

my team created a project in Frame Maker and we want to convert it to DITA (that will be edited with Frame Maker). The conversion is done with Mif2go. It is complicated step and the DITA files may contain incomplete information. I was suggested to validate them using Eclipse (Kepler).

The DITA version of the files is 1.1 (the default of Mif2Go). I was needed to copy the DITA library files to eclipse workspace in order to validate the XML (including, for example, bookmap.dtd, bookmap.mod, and more). However, I get many errors for theese files when I validate the workspace of eclipse. For example, in the file "metaDecl.mod", i get error for the line "!ELEMENT author        (%words.cnt;)*".
The error says: 
" A '(' character or an element type is required in the declaration of element type "author"."

I get this error for many DITA files and I don't understand why.
I will extremely appreciate any clue...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell based on your question and without understanding the Mif2go conversion.

I'd start with ensuring you have the Web Tools Platform (www.eclipse.org/webtools) installed in Eclipse. This includes XML validation. You may also want to download the DITA-OT from https://github.com/dita-ot and unzip it to your Eclipse workspace folder and add it as a project.

I am using Eclipse to convert HTML to DITA and validation seems to work OK on my DITA files. It may also be that Mif2go is writing out some bad XML; that .mod file is part of the DITA-OT, so that's probably not the issue. Maybe you can try removing the offending line and trying to validate again.